# Who can I contact if I want to create a new tag, but I don't have the reputation points?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I would like to create a new tag "graphpad-prism" on Superuser to flag questions on Graphpad Prism (a statistical program commonly used in biotech and pharma companies). Superuser appears to be the right place to list because it contains questions on e.g. Excel.

I am blocked from creating tags because I don't have sufficient reputation points on Superuser.

I understand the need to restrict the number and reputation of people who create tags to make sure that they are created appropriately, however would the administrators consider providing an address to which new users can "suggest" a new tag?

Comment: This seems pretty specialised, how many questions do you anticipate would use it?

Comment: It looks like your question is only the second one involving this software.  The other one was actually about just embedding its graphic output in Word  (so the tag probably wouldn't even be relevant there), and that one never got an answer.  This might be the appropriate SE site, but it could be a case of the software being too specialized to have a base of experts here.  Even if the tag is created, the system would automatically delete it in 6 months if there has not been at least one more question using the tag.  With no followers, the tag won't be generally helpful in attracting answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you found, all users - not just site moderators - with sufficient reputation can create tags. Therefore, you can ask right here on meta! If there are existing questions that should have the tag, include them in your meta question. In this case, it's clear what the tag should be used for, but in cases where it's not, make sure to include some explanation about why the tag would be helpful.

If you're posting a new question in an area without an appropriate tag, apply the most relevant one you can find. You can then add a comment asking a user with sufficient privileges to add the tag, and/or you could create a meta question. [Relevant MSE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94281/295684)