# Please create a tag for "graphpad-prism"

Tags: feature-request, tags

Please could you create a tag on Superuser for "graphpad-prism"?

Here's a description:
A statistical graphing program widely used in Academia and the Biotech and Pharma industries.

Two questions that should be assigned to this tag are:
Q: Convert data from columns to replicates in Graphpad Prism and
Q: Word Template for Automatic Object Placement?

Graphpad Prism's website is https://graphpad.com/

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who can I contact if I want to create a new tag, but I don't have the reputation points?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/12097/who-can-i-contact-if-i-want-to-create-a-new-tag-but-i-dont-have-the-reputation)

Comment: As mentioned on the other Meta question, the tag would not be relevant to the second question.  Tags should reflect what the question is about, not just things mentioned.

Comment: @fixer1234: I apologize for my mistake; please tell me what I should have done. From my point of view, this is a follow-up, not a duplicate. Answering my original question "Who can I contact..." Ben N replied "Therefore, you can ask right here on meta" and he asked for additional information. I therefore asked the second question, on meta, providing additional details. I felt this was correct because "Please create the tag X" is inherently a different question to "How do I create I tag?".

Comment: Freda, it looks like people are talking across each other.  :-)  Ben N provided an answer to the literal question to serve as general information.  But that question also served as a tag request.  The tag information posted here could be added to the original question.  However, I think nobody created the tag for the reasons described there.  Your question is currently the only one that would use the tag.  It doesn't serve a useful purpose to have a tag for a single question.  Also, this won't be a good place for people to get answers if there are only a few people familiar with the software.

Comment: If you REALLY think a tag would be worthwhile, what about asking another question about the software?  That would provide the minimum for the system to not delete the tag.  If it isn't a self-answered question, the extent to which it attracts answers will also indicate how useful the tag will be here.

Comment: @fixer1234: 3 out of 5 Research Articles in Science Magazine (2/10/17) contain graphs that appear to have been made in Graphpad Prism, the dominant software used for graphing in biology labs. The question "Word Template for Automatic Object Placement?" should contain a tag for Graphpad Prism because the question might be easy to answer in Prism, but difficult in Excel and Word. I'll try to do that :) Lastly, with no tag for graphpad-prism, users are discouraged from asking questions about this software.

Comment: re: your last sentence, lack of a tag didn't seem to be an obstacle to posting your own question.  :-)  I went ahead and created a tag.  But be aware that the system will automatically delete the tag if there is not at least one more question in the next six months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered in comment #7.
Fixer1234 created the tag.